# Как протестировать удаление объекта в JUnit?

Tags: java, javafx

нужно протестировать функцию Food eat() в JUnit: убедится в том, что функция всё же удалила объект из списка.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

    /**
     * Класс Человек
     */
    class Human {

        /** Имя человека*/
        private String name;

        /**
         * Конструктор по умолчанию
         */
        Human() {
            name = "";
        }

        /**
         * Конструктор с параметрами
         * @param name имя человека
         */
        Human (String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        /**
         * Сетер имени человека
         * @param n имя человека
         */
        void setName(String n) {
            name = n;
        }

        /**
         * @return имя человека
         */
        String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        /**
         * Метод "кушания". Удаляет блюдо из списка
         * @param foods список блюд
         * @return блюдо
         */
        Food eat(ArrayList<Food> foods) {
            Food f = foods.get(foods.size()-1);
            foods.remove(foods.size()-1);
            return f;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class HumanTest {
    List<Food> list;

    @Before
    public void prepareList(){
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Food("meat"));
        list.add(new Food("fruits"));
        list.add(new Food("fish"));
    }

    @Test
    public void eatReturnLastFoodFromList() {

    }

    @Test
    public void eatRemovLastFoodFromList() {
        Human h = new Human();
        h.eat(list);
        assertFalse(list.contains(new Food("fish")));
        assertTrue(list.size() == 2);
    }

}
```

Comment: `list.contains(new Food("fish"))` всегда будет false, ибо вы создаете новый объект `Food`, который никогда не мог быть в списке, так как только что был создан.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, метод `eat()` можно упростить:

```
Food eat(ArrayList<Food> foods) {
        return foods.remove(foods.size() - 1);
}
```

Тест очень простой, если ссылки на объекты `Food` не повторяются в вашем списке (т.е. один и тот же объект не добавлен два раза в список). Нужно проверить, что размер списка уменьшился на единицу, что съеден именно последний объект, что съеденный объект больше не в списке:

```
@BeforeMethod
public void setUp() {
    //prepare foodList and human objects
}

@Test
public static void testEatMethod() {
    int size = foodList.size();
    Food foodToBeDeleted = foodList.get(foodList.size() - 1);
    Food foodDeleted = human.eat(foodList);
    assertEquals(foodDeleted, foodToBeDeleted);
    assertEquals(foodList.size(), size - 1);
    assertFalse(foodList.contains(foodToBeDeleted));
}
```

Comment: а подскажите что именно нужно прописать в блоке 
public void setUp() {???}

Comment: @Daniil создать объекты `ArrayList<Food> foodList` и `Human human`. И наполнить `foodList` едой